# Classification Task with a survey: Getting rid of questions that are not answered by people in given coutries

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, missing-data

Good Afternoon, I am having some issues with a survey dataset of this type

```
Id Nation Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 .... Var200
 1 Italy   1    NA   2    3
 2 Italy   2    NA   2    1
 3 Italy   1    NA   1    0
 4 France  1    1    NA   5
 5 France  1    2    5    3
 6 Italy   5    NA   2    6 
 7 Spain   NA   1    2    5 
 8 Spain   NA   1    3    NA
 9 France  4    2    2    4
 10 Italy  NA   NA   2    3
 11 Spain  NA   2    1    1
```

basically, there are a lot of missing values, and the main problem is that there are some variables that have all missing values for some countries (in this example var2 has no value recorded for Italy, while var1 has no value for Spain).
I am trying to apply a classification tree to predict the country of origin.
since I would like to reconstruct some missing values using PCA (does it sound reasonable to you?)  or something like that,
 I first need to get rid of the questions that have no record for specific countries (like a method to discard a variable if there is no recorded value for at least one of the Nations in the dataset).
how can I do to eliminate those variables?

for this specific example this is what i would like to obtain something like this

```
Id Nation Var3 Var4 .... Var200
 1 Italy   2    3  ...
 2 Italy   2    1  ...
 3 Italy   1    0
 4 France  NA   5
 5 France  5    3
 6 Italy   2    6 
 7 Spain   2    5 
 8 Spain   3    NA
 9 France  2    4
 10 Italy  2    3
 11 Spain  1    1
```

thank you in advance for your help,

Best,
Carlo

Comment: @RonakShah I modified the question, I hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0):

If we want to ignore the complete column if there is even one `Nation` with all `NA` in it, we can do

```
cols <- grep("^Var", names(df))
df1 <- aggregate(.~Nation, df[-1], function(x) all(is.na(x)), na.action = na.pass)

df1
#  Nation  Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4
#1 France FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#2  Italy FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#3  Spain  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

`df1` gives us the value of if there are any countries which has all `NA`s in that column.

```
cbind(df[1:2], df[cols][colSums(df1[-1]) == 0])

#   Id Nation Var3 Var4
#1   1  Italy    2    3
#2   2  Italy    2    1
#3   3  Italy    1    0
#4   4 France   NA    5
#5   5 France    5    3
#6   6  Italy    2    6
#7   7  Spain    2    5
#8   8  Spain    3   NA
#9   9 France    2    4
#10 10  Italy    2    3
#11 11  Spain    1    1
```

---

A one-liner base R option using `sapply` and `ave`

```
cbind(df[1:2], df[cols][sapply(df[cols], function(x) 
               !any(ave(is.na(x), df$Nation, FUN = all)))])
```

---

Using `dplyr` we could find out names of columns which has no `Nation` as all `NA`'s and `select` them along with `Nation` and `Id`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(Id, Nation, df %>%
  group_by(Nation) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Var")), funs(all(is.na(.)))) %>%
  select(-Nation) %>%
  select_if(funs(sum(.) == 0)) %>%
  names())
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Id = 1:11, Nation = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("France", "Italy", "Spain"
), class = "factor"), Var1 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, NA, NA, 
4L, NA, NA), Var2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 
2L), Var3 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), Var4 = c(3L, 
1L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, NA, 4L, 3L, 1L)), .Names = c("Id", "Nation", 
"Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: thank you for your super detailed answer Ronak, I will try it now :)